# How to launch a QThread correctly

Tags: c++, qt, googletest

I think I'm missing something obvious here.

I'd like to Run GTest with the QT Eventloop. For the QT Eventloop to run I have to start the QApplication.

The GTEST RUN_ALL_TESTS should then start inside a newly created QThread.

```
/**
 * @brief Executes GTest. After Executing GTest it will stop the QApllication
*/
static void ExecuteGTest();


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  auto pGTest = std::make_unique<QThread>(QThread::create(ExecuteGTest));
  pGTest->start();
  const int iGTestRes = app.exec();
  return iGTestRes;
}

static void ExecuteGTest()
{
  const int iRes = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  //terminate the Qt Eventloop and return GTest Result
  QCoreApplication::exit(iRes);
}
```

However ExecuteGTest() is never executed. What am i missing here? Could you help me out?

Comment: You spawn the thread but the main application thread never waits for it to complete.

Comment: Before your `main` exits, try adding `pGText->wait();` and remove the app exit call from the thread function.

Comment: hey yes you're right ;) this was another error. I added a ```pGTest->wait();``` after app.exec()
However the main Problem still exist: when i set a breakpoint at the beginning of ExecuteGTest() my program will never get here =>so the QThread is not actually running. Do have an Idea why?

Comment: QThread needs event loop to work, `app.exec()` starts the event loop, you need to start event loop and then call `pGText->wait()`, so you need to call wait asyncronously, for example with zero timer and lambda `QTimer::singleShot(0,[=](){pGText->wait();});` (before `app.exec();`)

Comment: thx your soltion makes sense. :) In combination with G.M. this works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the statement...

```
auto pGTest = std::make_unique<QThread>(QThread::create(ExecuteGTest));
```

Generally speaking an expression...

```
std::make_unique<T>(args...)
```

will create an `std::unique_ptr<T>` with the instance of `T` being constructed according to...

```
T(args...)
```

So in this case you will actually invoke the [`QThread` constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#QThread) that accepts a `QObject *` as its parent object...

```
QThread::QThread(QObject *parent = nullptr)
```

When you subsequently invoke `pGTest->start()` you're actually calling `start` on a child object of the `QThread` created by `QThread::create(ExecuteGTest)`.

Try changing the aforementioned statement to...

```
std::unique_ptr<QThread> pGTest(QThread::create(ExecuteGTest));
```

Comment: thx. Your solution works in combination with the QTimer solution above :)
I completely missed that QThread::Create already returned a Pointer. So there is no need for make_unique :)